# How do I top start the hint text within an TextInputEditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need [top|start] hint text an TextInputEditText..
I use `android:gravity="top|start"` hint text still in center, but the text content is correct (top start)

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="200">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:text="@={textProg.textProg.text}"
                android:hint="Hint Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:maxLength="200"
                android:textColor="@drawable/edit_text_color"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: has been fixed by Material Android team [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/a040af5bd3a4e429f5d1323e72519e002ef4f4bb)

Answer (score 1):

i don't know why your code doesn't work with you it work with me , but you can try this i hope it work .

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"
                    app:counterMaxLength="200">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:text="@={textProg.textProg.text}"
                        android:hint="Hint Text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:ellipsize="start"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:maxLength="200"
                        />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: stil not work,, I think this is because an issue related to material design library.. other people experience the same thing in material:1.2.0-alpha04.. [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/933)

Comment: This is possible , if you didn't update your app and android studio please do it maybe it work , good luck .

Answer (score 0):

why you not try by adding this `android:ellipsize="top|start"`

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's an issue related to material design library. I have checked with different version and found different scenarios for same `layout`. Among them below version gives me the result that you want to achieve.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I think so, other people experience the same thing in material:1.2.0-alpha04.. [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/933)

Comment: Have you tried with `1.2.0-alpha01`? I have checked **01-04** and found **01** only works. Besides this **1.0.0** also works

Comment: @LinggaMG, If this help you then please accept the answer

Comment: Sorry because yesterday I was a little busy .. I have tried and it is like that, but i need alpha02++, because there are prefixText and suffixText (maybe the bug is caused because of this).. it looks like I'll wait until 1.2 has the final version.